# PHP: Class not found in subdirectory

Tags: php, directory, include

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

dbh.class.php connects to a database and test.class.php gets the data from my database. When I am in my index.php and use the following code:

```
include_once 'classes/dbh.class.php';
include_once 'classes/test.class.php';
$testobjekt = new Test();
$testobjekt->getUsers();
```

I get my desired result.

But when I try to call the classes and their methods with the same code in the subdirectory public/home.php I get an error:

```
Warning: include_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/funktionstest/public/classes/dbh.class.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/funktionstest/public/home.php on line 4
```

What am I doing wrong when I want to call the classes from a subdirectory? I tried it with absolute paths `include_once __DIR__ . '/classes/test.class.php';` But it still does not work.

Comment: The warning should have been a giveaway - it showed the path where it tried to find it: `funktionstest/public/classes/`. Relative includes (such as yours) always search from the directory of the current script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

home.php is in public dir. So you need to add `..`.
`..` means parent directory.

Try:

```
include_once '../classes/dbh.class.php';
include_once '../classes/test.class.php';
```